# Spring 2 JDBC datasource configuration

Tags: spring, jdbc

I am currently looking at an application that uses Spring and Spring JDBC.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html

I can't find from the doc ways / where to configure settings such as set pool size, re-connection, test on borrow.

Am i missing something here? I am new to Spring. Is it that this plain vanilla JDBC option does not allow me to do what is described or is it that i would need something like c3po library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These properties are not part of Spring but underlying `DataSource` implementation. First you have to include some database pooling library like [dbcp](/questions/tagged/dbcp):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Once you added this library you configure the provided `DataSource` implementation:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pwd" />
    <property name="url" value="some:url" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="some.class.Driver" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
</bean>
```

You can also choose different `DataSource` implementations like [c3p0](/questions/tagged/c3p0). Finally you can obtain `DataSource` configured in your application server, e.g. using [jndi](/questions/tagged/jndi). Spring JDBC support uses any `DataSource` implementation provided. Also Spring ships with some very simple [`DriverManagerDataSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) intended for testing.

Comment: Thanks, can i also ask, if without DBCP / C3PO, does it mean that Spring JDBC will fall back on default settings, something which we do not know?

Comment: @ChinBoon: no, you **must** provide bean implementing `DataSource` interface and Spring will not use any default/fallback data source. It will most likely fail to start.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, what if the connection (and pooling) is managed, e.g. by WebLogic.

Comment: @ChinBoon: then WebLogic allows you to lookup this connection pool (`DataSource`) via [tag:jndi] (or maybe using some proprietary API)?