# Connection pooling in spring jdbc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have implemented spring jdbc in my project. I am just curious to know how connection pooling in handled in spring jdbc? If spring is taking care of connections, then where can I specify the max number of connections allowed for my application?

Another question is how is connection pooling handled in simple jdbc.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use own custom datasource, like this:

```
<bean id="springDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SPRING_TEST" />
   <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
   <property name="username" value="root" />
   <property name="password" value="root" />
   <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
   <property name="initialSize" value="20" />
   <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
</bean>

//Dao class configuration in spring
 <bean id="EmployeeDatabaseBean" class="com.test.EmployeeDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="springDataSource"/>
 </bean>
```

Official [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-datasource)

[Here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/06/jdbc-database-connection-pool-in-spring.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10495032/4264819) described pretty simple.